# Вопрос по опенкарт

Tags: php, opencart, sitemap

Вывожу карту сайта `html`, то-есть, категории, и под каждой категорией товар из этой категории. Вопрос, как при выводе ссылки на товар, в `title` ссылки вставить `мета-description` из товара. Вот так вывожу товар. Заранее спасибо!

```
$this->data['products'] = array();

$product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data); 

$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($data);

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $this->data['products'][] = array(
        'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
        'name'        => $result['name'],
        'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю так:

```
$title = $this->document->getTitle().' '.$this->document->getDescription();
$this->document->setTitle($title);
```